# microsoft virtual wifi miniport adapter has been replaced by

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, hotspot, hp-elitebook, windows-phone-8

`Microsoft virtual wifi miniport adapter` has been replaced by `Microsoft Wi-Fi direct Virtual adapter` in Windows 8; I think.

I created hosted network using

`netsh wlan show drivers`

`netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=TEST key=12345678`

`netsh wlan start hostednetwork`

I am unable to connect to the hot-spot from my Lumia. It says that **my computer did not respond**. However, “netsh wlan show hostednetwork” shows “one authenticated user”

PS C:> netsh wlan show hostednetwork

### Hosted network settings

```
Mode                   : Allowed
SSID name              : "Test"
Max number of clients  : 10
Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
Cipher                 : CCMP
```

### Hosted network status

```
Status                 : Started
BSSID                  : a2:88:b4:7f:31:9c
Radio type             : 802.11n
Channel                : 11
Number of clients      : 1
    a8:44:81:05:e3:64        Authenticated`
```

My phone connects fine to other Wifi networks. I'm sure it's my laptop[8460p] I need to tweak.